# DanielGindi Chart, increase bottom space between chart and Legend. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am trying to increase the space between a chart and a legend in iOS Swift. But I haven’t been able to achieve it.

My present code looks something like this:

```
override func configureChartView() {
    super.configureChartView()

    chartView.borderColor = .zinc
    chartView.legend.enabled = true

}

override func configureLegend() {
    super.configureLegend()

    let legend = chartView.legend
    legend.form = .square
    legend.xOffset = 0.0

    // increase spacing between legends
    legend.xEntrySpace = 20.0
    legend.orientation = .horizontal

    legend.yOffset = 6.00
    legend.formSize = 15.0
}
```

I attached an image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
chartView.extraBottomOffset = 10
```